# Plotting using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mpg) +  
  geom_point(aes(x = displ^2, x = hwy)
             mpgfil = fliter(mpg, cyl = 8)
             mpg_manu= select(mpg, starts_with("man") & ends_with("rv")
```

And a lot of various errors occur.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to achieve, & where you are facing problems?

Comment: @immaprogrammingnoob, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: It looks like you may need to take a step back and take a moment to learn some ggplot2 basics. The examples in the online (in-R) manual pages are meant to do that as are resources such as http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html. I've also edited your code to show how following some coding style may help point out errors. Finally, you've not followed the guidelines on submission that @Artem kindly re-linked. Where do `select` and `filter` (assuming it's not `base::filter`) come from and what resource suggested using them in that way (i.e. in `geom_point()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for `ggplot` part you made typo in a code: the second argument should be substituted from `x` to `y`, as the points you are plotting should have two coordinates.

As for `filter` and `select` helpers you have multiple typos, as well as you cannot use `&` operator to create conditions for column selection:

Please see the corrected code below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data = mpg) +  geom_point(aes(x = displ^2, y = hwy)) 
mpgfil <- filter(mpg, cyl == 8)
head(mpgfil)
# # A tibble: 6 x 11
# manufacturer model              displ  year   cyl trans    drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
# <chr>        <chr>              <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>    <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
#   1 audi         a6 quattro           4.2  2008     8 auto(s6) 4        16    23 p     midsize
# 2 chevrolet    c1500 suburban 2wd   5.3  2008     8 auto(l4) r        14    20 r     suv    
# 3 chevrolet    c1500 suburban 2wd   5.3  2008     8 auto(l4) r        11    15 e     suv    
# 4 chevrolet    c1500 suburban 2wd   5.3  2008     8 auto(l4) r        14    20 r     suv    
# 5 chevrolet    c1500 suburban 2wd   5.7  1999     8 auto(l4) r        13    17 r     suv    
# 6 chevrolet    c1500 suburban 2wd   6    2008     8 auto(l4) r        12    17 r     suv   

mpg_manu <- select(mpg, starts_with("man")) %>%  select(ends_with("rv"))
head(mpg_manu)
# A tibble: 6 x 0
```

Output:
[image: graph]